# why is elasticbeanstalk url not accessible whereas loadbalancer url for the same environment is?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk setup but the url that's listed in the environment is not accessible, whereas if I point to the url of the load balancer I can access it.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Attach the LoadBalancer security group to the instance. For me it worked. I found ELB has different security group that is not attached to instance.
Or you can create one Security Group with HTTP port 80 open and attach it to ELB and Instance from the beanstalk configuration

Answer (score -1):

Go to Elastic Beanstalk configuration then go to VPC settings. Check the "Associate Public IP Address". Then it worked for me.